# Best Python library for web scraping that uses XPath?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping

I am using Selenium Webdriver at the moment, it works perfectly but it isn't what I am looking for. What I don't like about the Selenium Webdriver is the fact that it runs a real session of the browser (I know there are some ways to run it in background). Is there any other library for web scraping that uses xpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best framework for this is Scrapy. It has a lot good stuff, like middleware, pipeline, spiders. You can use it alone or with an additional library like Selenium, request, proxy, etc...
If you want to use Selenium - PyVirtualDisplay will help you to hide browser window